# How do I have my inline-flex go to the bottom of my page

Tags: css

I'm trying to find out how the flex-inline works; how do I go about having it expand height to 100% and touch the bottom of the screen, without filling it full of stuff.

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0}
body{background:black;}



#sidebar{
  display: inline-flex ;
  flex-direction: column;
  border:5px solid blue;
  background:white;
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
  list-style: none;
}

span {color:blue;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id=sidebar>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  </div>
   <span>hello</span>
</body>
```

Comment: Relatable to https://gyazo.com/79f9de0e2fb26d45157919249e5e2b19

you see how it goes from the top to the bottom of the page, I'm unable to do that for myself, can someone link refs on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `height: 100vh`.
`vh` - view height

Comment: To scale it with width I guess I use vw? Also, for the stuff inside do I need to follow vh/vw or can I just use %tages.

Comment: a better way would be set the body with the 100vh or calc(100vh - 20px), 20px can be the size of the border or another component. And set `height: -webkit-fill-available;` or 100% for the child elements that you need.

Comment: But I do have to use VH/VW to get what I see on the Facebook page like that's the best and most efficient way?

Comment: I used to do in that way, but I found a big discussion about that topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window

Comment: So are you running with vh or %?

Comment: vh when it has to be relative to the screen size and % when it has to be relative to the component/element size.

Comment: Thanks, so you mostly use vh for objects such as that navbar/sidebar/ major divs on the page, and use the %'s for the stuff within the divs?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way based on your current code is to use viewport units `height:100vh;`.

***vh unit***

vh was initially calculated by the current viewport of your browser. If you opened your browser and started to load a website, 1vh was equal to 1% of your screen height, minus the browser interface.

so css need to be changed by :

height: calc(100vh - 40px); as sidebar - to avoid any unnecessary scrolls

border = 20px top and bottom

```css
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
body {
    background:black;
}
#sidebar {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border:0px solid blue;
    background:white;
    width:20%;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:center;
    list-style: none;
    background:#00CCCC;
    height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}
span {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div id=sidebar>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</div>
<span>hello</span>
```

Comment: thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would suggest you to keep

`height = 100vh - border(top + bottom) of the div` (depending on flex orientation) to avoid any unnecessary scrolls when using `vh`.

so in this case it would be

`height: calc(100vh - 10px);` as `sidebar border = 5px top and bottom`

```css
    html,body{margin:0;padding:0}
    body{background:black;}



    #sidebar{
      display: inline-flex ;
      height: calc(100vh - 10px);
      flex-direction: column;
      border:5px solid blue;
      background:white;
      width:20%;
      text-align:center;
      list-style: none;
    }

    span {color:blue;
      position:relative;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
      <div id=sidebar>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      </div>
       <span>hello</span>
    </body>
```

Comment: Oh yeah heavily.